# xslt to convert hours and mins (number) to PT*H*M

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

New to xslt. Looking for an xslt1.0 to convert the time that will be entered by client in hours and mins to this format PT*H*M

```
 <cre:timeTotal>1</cre:timeTotal> to  <cre:timeTotal>PT1H</cre:timeTotal>
<cre:timeTotal>6.5</cre:timeTotal> to <cre:timeTotal>PT6H30M</cre:timeTotal>
<cre:timeTotal>6.5</cre:timeTotal> to <cre:timeTotal>PT30M</cre:timeTotal>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The entry you show is NOT "in hours and mins"; it is in decimal hours. And I believe that last one should be 0.5 ,not 6.5.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
<xsl:template match="cre:timeTotal">
    <xsl:variable name="h" select="floor(.)" />
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="60 * (. - $h)" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:text>PT</xsl:text> 
        <xsl:if test="$h">
            <xsl:value-of select="$h"/>
            <xsl:text>H</xsl:text>  
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$m">
            <xsl:value-of select="$m"/>
            <xsl:text>M</xsl:text>  
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

---

P.S. If your processor happens to support the EXSLT [date:duration()](http://exslt.org/date/functions/duration/index.html) extension function, you could do simply:

```
<xsl:value-of select="date:duration(3600 * .)"/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. it doesnt support exslt

Comment: Is this question not answered?